# ruby cut out text from string to arrays

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have code code like

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

def bash_org()
  bash = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://bash.org/?random"),'utf-8')
  bash = bash.css("p[class='qt']").text
  print(bash.gsub("\n","").gsub("\t",""))
end

def print(text)
  if text.include? "\r"
    text = text.split("\r")
    text.each do |line|
      if !line.empty?
        puts line
      end
    end
  else
    text = text.split("<")
    text.each do |line|
      if !line.empty?
        puts "<#{line}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Everything is working great except I can not distinguish single quotes that are between class="qa" tags.

I would like to extract single quotes from bash random page and put them into separate arrays.

Comment: I was thinking about trying to search this text in a loop with something like 'do until' and assign text to array, but maybe there is a better option?

Comment: what are `qa`s? I see only `quote` and `qt` classes in the HTML code

Comment: Also, your code filters everything properly and returns the text. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you strip "\n" and split on "\r"? That's making an assumption your text will have carriage returns, which isn't a safe thing to assume. The standard line ending is "\n".

Comment: yeah, my mistake i wanted to write "qt" not "qt" sorry!

Comment: I would like to separate all quotes. Something like one quote into one array. Now I have everything in one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind my comments. I think I've just noticed it.

Currently your code gets "all the `qt` tags" and extracts the text from them as whole. This way, you get one huge blob of text that in fact cannot be "separated" into single posts.

You have all the bits in place, but you've joined them wrong. Nokogiri's `css` operator returns a **collection** of matches. Just iterate over it instead of `.text`ing it.

Please review this one:

```
def bash_org()
  bash = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://bash.org/?random"),'utf-8')
  tags = bash.css("p[class='qt']")    #<-- no .text here!

  tags.each{|tag|     #<-- loop over them!
    txt = tag.text    #<-- text'ize them one-by-one

    print(txt.gsub("\n","").gsub("\t",""))
    puts '------'
  }
end
```

Note the indicated differences. Once you notice that the "tags" are collection of "tag" objects, it'll be obvious.

Comment: so "tags = bash.css("p[class='qt']")" treats text from between qt tags as a single element? thats why I print everything in a loop, yes? or am i wrong? thanks for answer anyway!

Comment: NO. `bash.css(xxxx)` returns a collection of items that match the search criteria `xxxx`. And you give xxxx=`p[class='qt']` which means "tags named P that have CLASS of QT". Hence, `tags = bash.css("p[class='qt']")` searches for p-tags-of-class-qt and stores the list of such tags in `tags` variable. Then you loop over that list and for each tag from the list you call `tag.text` on it to get a text from just one tag at a time.

Comment: Earlier, when you called `bash.css("p[class='qt']").text`. Note that this is not the same. It has `.text` at the end. So, you asked for the collection of matches and then you asked it for text. So you've actually asked for "all the text from all the items that matched the xxxx", so you got all the text. At once. By not doing that and by looping over the collection, you are looking at the items one-by-one and asking each of them for its text separately - so you get the separate quotes, one-by-one. Not all at once.